# Unable to select a menu item with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I am making a screen scraper using the Selenium Python library and I have already made some code so that I can log in. For some reason I am now stuck on the main menu and can't select any of the options. I have tried using CSS Selector, Class Name, and XPATH and none have been able to select any of the possible choices. No matter what happens, I always get a `TimeoutException` even with a long delay.

The portion of the page I am trying to scrape from is [here](https://github.com/cp-community/Cut-and-Paste/blob/main/Screen%20Scrape%20Menu).

The relevant code is as follows:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Open browser and go to the Webex login page
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://admin.webex.com')

delay = 10  # seconds
long_delay = 20

# Login portion removed

# Menu selection goes here.

# I have tried the following with no luck
# The following lines produce a TimeoutException error

# Selecting menu item
WebDriverWait(driver, long_delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "span[@class='left-nav-item__link']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, long_delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//mch-left-nav-item-group[4]/ul/mch-left-nav-item[3]/li/span'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, long_delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//webex-root/webex-main[@class='control-hub-container']//webex-sidebar/mch-left-nav/nav/mch-left-nav-item-group[4]/ul/mch-left-nav-item[3]//span[@class='left-nav-item__link']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, long_delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='left-nav-item__link']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-label] mch-left-nav-item-group:nth-of-type(4) mch-left-nav-item:nth-of-type(3) .left-nav-item__link"))).click()

# Selecting group of items
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'left-nav-item')))
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.left-nav-item')))

# Selecting parent
WebDriverWait(driver, long_delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-test-name='calling']")))
```

Does anyone have an idea why I'm not able to select any element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone having this issue.

When a new tab is opened while you are using Selenium, even though you are viewing the new page, Selenium is not. You have to switch to the correct window. Something such as the following can help you with that.

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[NUMBER])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xpath for the third one:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, long_delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "span[@class='left-nav-item__link']"))).click()
```

Comment: I just tried using the XPATH but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Let me rephrase. Using the XPATH above give me the exact same error, `TimeoutException`.

Comment: But for which line? Just edit your question and post the full error message.

Comment: Which line? Any and all of them I have listed in the code above and the one you suggested. They all time out. They all give `TimeoutException`. If I put your suggestion at the top then that is the line that the error will occur. If another one of the ones that I tried is higher then that one has the error.